# What does ` {…}` mean?

Tags: go

In a lot of go repositories in many places generally, when error responses are generated i see
`if error != nil {…}`

What does `{…}` mean here.

Answer (score 2):

In this case '{...}' is not really a Golang syntactic construct but just usage of ellipsis to say "here in this {} block you should do something to handle error". It is just placeholder for subjective code to handle error in a way that makes sense in your use case. People do that in documentation to keep examples not-cluttered by error handling logic but still highlighting proper usage of library including error handling.

For completeness there are other places in Golang where `...` actually has a special meaning. Those places are:

- As argument to `go` command `...` means recursive package list wildcard. `go test ./...` will test **all** golang packages found in directory './' and any level of subdirectories
- Array literals `arr := [...]string{"foo", "bar"}` will substitute `...` with number of items in array literal, here it will be 2. If you add "baz" at some point, you don't have to update number in [].
- Variadic function arguments `func foo(args ...int)` - see [here](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions).
- When passing a slice to a variadic function you can unwrap it by adding `...` and each element of the slice will be passed as an additional argument. See `sum(nums...)` in example linked above.